# Nullable parameter type <T> for a generic method?

Tags: c#, types, pivot, generics

I'm using the pivot method presented at:
http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=147

My question is: How can i use a nullable type  as the second generic key?

```
public static Dictionary<TFirstKey, Dictionary<TSecondKey, TValue>> Pivot<TSource, TFirstKey, TSecondKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TFirstKey> firstKeySelector, Func<TSource, TSecondKey> secondKeySelector, Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TValue> aggregate) {
        var retVal = new Dictionary<TFirstKey, Dictionary<TSecondKey, TValue>>();

        var l = source.ToLookup(firstKeySelector);
        //l.Dump("Lookup first key");
        foreach (var item in l) {
            var dict = new Dictionary<TSecondKey, TValue>();
            retVal.Add(item.Key, dict);
            var subdict = item.ToLookup(secondKeySelector);
            foreach (var subitem in subdict) {
                dict.Add(subitem.Key, aggregate(subitem));
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: What's your compilation or runtime error?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a nullable *type* just normally as long as the values aren't null - but you **can't** use `null` (or an empty `Nullable<T>`) as a key - it simply can't work.

It would make more sense to ensure (in the calling code) that `secondKeySelector` always returns something non-null; in the case of `Nullable<T>` perhaps by calling `x => x.Foo.Value` (if you see what I mean).

Another approach would be to declaratively preclude `Nullable<T>` here, by adding `where TSecondKey : struct` - but since `string` is a common key (and is a reference-type) this may be an undesirable approach.

Comment: First line of your answer helped me solve this issue. Thanks Marc.

Answer (score 0):

You can be explicit on the use of the `Nullable<T>` on your generic declaration, which will limit you to use a `Nullable` on your method.

```
public static Dictionar<TFirstKey, Dictionary<Nullable<TSecondKey>, TValue>> Pivot<TSource, TFirstKey, TSecondKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TFirstKey> firstKeySelector, Func<TSource, Nullable<TSecondKey>> secondKeySelector, Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TValue> aggregate)
  where TSecondKey : struct
{}
```

As your using a `Nullable<T>`, you have to repeat the constraint for `T` to your implementation.

Please also note that `Dictionary` might not be happy with null key.

Comment: If dictionary won't be happy with a null key, I see *absolutely* no benefit in using `Nullable<TSecondKey>` here. That just adds extra overhead for every value, when **we know** that each must be non-null. It also precludes using `string` as a key; there are two keys I use mainly; `string` and `int`.

Comment: That wouldn't work, check IDictionary`2 documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx . There's no contravariance for this interface, so you can't cast Dictionary<SomeNullable, ...> to Dictionary<Nullable<T>, ....

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer Both the key selector and the `Dictionary`'s key are the same type, so there is no variance in the types.